# How can I make an inline select in materializeCss

Tags: material-design, materialize

How can I make such a select??
[image]

tried to do `display: inline` but it did not work out

Comment: Can you give the url for the reference ?

Comment: @Ranjit, https://jsfiddle.net/Jussia/e240zmzb/

Comment: Please see the answer and accept it.

Comment: did you get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do the following.

Change the HTML part `<div class="input-field col s1 inline">` to " `<div class="input-field col s12 inline">`".

and use the css for inline

```
.input-field p, .input-field .select-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
```